# How To Access Fields of nested dictionary in PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

My problem is albeit a bit atypical. My Mongo instance records appear as follows:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("559670400084d37ea4cafa29"),
"('7412791816', '3838144', '723031613')" : {
    "Customer_Loc_PinCode" : "110035",
    "Net_Delivery_Time" : 3,
    "Manifest_Date" : ISODate("2015-04-04T00:00:00Z"),
    "Shipping_Date" : ISODate("2015-04-05T00:00:00Z"),
    "Shipping_Method_Code" : "COD",
    "Origin_PinCode" : "382470",
    "Net_Manifest_Time" : 0,
    "Transition_State" : [
        [
            "DNE",
            "CTD",
            "NULL",
            "2015-04-05 15:23:22",
            "NULL"
        ],
        ...# Many more such tuples present within this list.
    ],
    "Net_Shipping_Time" : 2,
    "RTD_Date" : "NULL",
    "Delivery_Date" : ISODate("2015-04-07T00:00:00Z"),
    "Intervening_Distance" : 522.3881079330106,
    "Awb_Number" : "723031613",
    "SubOrder_Number" : "7412791816",
    "Last_Status" : "SHP",
    "Customer_LatLong" : [
        -,#Some float value
        -#Some float value
    ],
    "Order_Date" : ISODate("2015-04-04T00:00:00Z"),
    "RTA_Date" : "NULL",
    "Return_Direction" : 0,
    "New_Status" : "DEL",
    "Origin_LatLong" : [
        -,#Some float value
        -
    ],
    "Rec_ID" : "3838144",
    "RTU_Date" : "NULL"
}}
```

Now I require to obtain the dates and Net_Delivery_Time, as an example here, for all the records for further processing(plotting).
 
However the major debacle is that each such dictionary is referenced by a composite key,i.e. a tuple consisting of 3 fields. Now each such key uniquely identifies the associated record. I wish to extract the required fields from each such dictionary, but I have no means of iterating through all the keys.
I tried an approach to first collect all the keys and then retrieve the concerned fields, but that method didn't ork as there is no associated support for that in PyMongo. 
If I were to use the db.'collection_name'.find() method, how will I craft the query? Can the uniqueness of each key present any potential problems? And what approach should I employ to achieve this task?
Thank You

Comment: Can you change the structure of this document? Does every document contain an _id and a dictionary with a key like "('7412791816', '3838144', '723031613')"? Example: `{_id:ObjectId(),("1,2,3"):dict}`

Comment: Yes, exactly, it's the same for each record. I can change the document structure, but a lot of time and effort has been spent in developing the data-set to the prescribed format. Changing it would entail repopulating the Mongo instance on the AWS server I'm working on and then restoring it to my local machine as well. So, even though it's very much possible, I would like to reserve it as a last resort. Otherwise, I'm curious, if it's at all possible?